# Using sjplot to create separate mini graphs and arrange them

Tags: graphing, sjplot

How do I unstack a plot in sjplot? I have a 5-category variable in my interaction term and I want a cluster of 5 mini graphs arranged in order for the figure (one graph for each category of that variable).

The graph is stacked right now.